# Crawling websites and dynamic urls

Tags: php, web, seo, web-crawler

Do search engine robots crawl my dynamically generated URLs? With this I mean html pages generated by php based upon GET variables in the url. The links would look like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/view.php?name=something
http://www.mywebsite.com/view.php?name=somethingelse
http://www.mywebsite.com/view.php?name=something
```

I have tried crawling my website with a test crawler found here: http://robhammond.co/tools/seo-crawler but it only visits my view page once, with just one variable in the header.

Most of the content on my website is generated by these GET variables from the database so I would really like the search engines to crawl those pages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because pure SEO questions are not programming related. It might be on topic for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'd use an `.htaccess` file to give your site some nice URLs in the form `www.mywebsite.com/something`, which is easier for the user to type, and more intuitive for the crawler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some search engines do, and some don't. Google for one does include dynamically generated pages: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en

Be sure to check your **robots.txt** file to ensure files you do *not* want the crawlers to see are blocked, and that files you *do* want indexed are not blocked.

Also, ensure that all pages you want indexed are linked via other pages, that you have a sitemap, or submit individual URLs to the search engine(s) you want to index your site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, search engines will crawl those pages, assuming they can find them.  Best thing to do is to simply create links to those pages on your website, particularly accessible, or at least traversable from the home page.